# PostGIS ST_LineMerge: why do 3 lines not merge, but any 2 do?

Tags: postgis

In PostGIS, `ST_LineMerge` is used to "stitch" several lines into a single `linestring`. If it cannot, it returns the original `multilinestring`.

I have a scenario where I have three lines in a set. They happen to be over a river. When I attempt to use `ST_LineMerge(geom[])` with three lines, it does not merge. However, using any two of the three lines *does* work!

Here is some code:

```
select ST_asText(ST_LineMerge(
  ST_Union(
    Array[
      -- THIS IS THE EAST-MOST LINE.
      -- The remaining lines start where this line ends.
      ST_GeomFromEWKT(
        'LINESTRING(-110.597626872104 45.0142399967956,-110.6000500721 45.0151951967941)'
      ),

      -- THIS IS THE MIDDLE SHORT LINE.
      -- NOTE: It falls just short of the third line.
      ST_GeomFromEWKT(
        'LINESTRING(-110.6000500721 45.0151951967941,-110.602446129524 45.0154430716088)'
      ),

      -- THIS IS THE LONGEST LINE.
      -- It appears to "contain" the second line.
      ST_GeomFromEWKT(
          'LINESTRING(-110.6000500721 45.0151951967941,-110.602478272096 45.0154463967937,-110.604730272093 45.0151811967941)'
      )
    ]
  )
))
```

Note that the second line is likely what's causing this problem. Each of these lines are (assumed to be) subsections of a river `linestring`. I believe that the middle line would be considered by PostGIS to be a subsection of the third line, even though they are *not* sharing more than one point. Indeed, the second line falls just short of the middle of the third line. When I replace the second coordinate of the second line to share the second coordinate of the third, it merges correctly.

Success in this case means these three lines are merged into one, and the new line's length is equal to the long western `linestring` plus the short east-most line. In other words, the new `linestring` is the simplest, shortest line possible.

[image: Three lines over a river: remove any one of these lines and they merge fine]

Comment: if truly *any two of the three lines* merge there's good reason to believe it is not going to work on all three. in fact, the only case where this *would* work is when there's a triangular connectivity between them (i.e. a *closed multilinestring*); the key word in the docs for `ST_LineMerge` is *'constituent'*, meaning that a line may only and exactly share one start/end point with a start/end point of another line. it does not dissolve overlapping lines or parts of them, and if there are only the tiniest of mismatches between coordinates, `ST_Union` will return a multipart `MULTILINESTRING`.

Comment: I believe if you pass an array, via, ST_Collect to ST_Linemerge you will get the result you expect, ie, ST_LineMerge(ST_Collect(linestrings)). I have used this to join multiple road segments together.